# CASE statement in FROM clause

Tags: select, case

Can you use `CASE` in the `FROM` clause of a `SELECT` statement to determine from which table to retrieve data?

My database has multiple versions of a table.  The value of an input parameter in a procedure will tell the procedure whether to retrieve data from version 1, 2 or 3.  The syntax I am trying to use is similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM (CASE input_parameter WHEN 1 THEN version1 WHEN 2 THEN version 2 WHEN 3 THEN version3 END) WHERE ...
```

Can this be done?  If so, am I using the correct syntax?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set table name in dynamic sql query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678725/how-to-set-table-name-in-dynamic-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done in the SQL statement itself. You'll need to construct the SQL statement dynamically in order to achieve this kind of result.

Answer (score 0):

You can't dynamically select the table like that in straight-up SQL. You would need a stored procedure to do exactly what you are wanting. There are some workarounds though.

You could do something janky in your FROM clause like:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM 
    (SELECT null as "whatever") as fakeTable
    LEFT OUTER JOIN version1 on input_parameter = 1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN version2 on input_parameter = 2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN version3 on input_parameter = 3
```

This will work since the input_parameter can only be one value at a time. Should you decide you want both version1 and version2 joined if the input_parameter is 2 then you will end up with a cross join and may god have mercy on your soul.

You could do something janky with a UNION:

```
SELECT * FROM version1 WHERE input_paramter=1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM version2 WHERE input_paramter=2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM version3 WHERE input_paramter=3
```

This is a bit nicer since a screw up will only bring back 2 or 3 times as many results instead of the screw up in example 1 where you get n^2 or n^3 results.

I'm not sure which one is going to cause more trouble from a CPU-I/O standpoint, but I would guess that they are pretty close from an execution path standpoint, and if the data is small, it probably won't matter anyway.