# SQL Server insert parameterized name table to IF EXISTS

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to insert `@inputData` to `ColumnData` if it doesn't exists to prevent duplicate data to a table with name as parameter `@TableName`. Error at the  'dbo.@TableName'.

```
SET @insertSQL = 'INSERT INTO '+ @TableName + ' (ColumnData) VALUES ('''+@inputData+''');'

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[@TableName] WHERE ColumnData = @inputData)
    EXECUTE(@insertData) -- EXECUTE @insertData if ColumnData is not found
```

I also tried this (also throws error):

```
SET @insertSQL = 'INSERT INTO '+ @TableName + ' (ColumnData) VALUES ('''+@inputData+''');'

IF NOT EXISTS (EXECUTE('SELECT 1 FROM [dbo]. '+@TableName ' WHERE ColumnData = ' + @inputData))
    EXECUTE(@insertData)   -- EXECUTE @insertData if ColumnData is not found
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: Replace if exists with if not exists ..

Comment: Invalid object name 'dbo.@Tablename' --The @Tablename didnt pass the parameter but instead use the '@Tablename' as its Table name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like you are splitting the dynamic SQL statement. Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName)  + ' WHERE ColumnData = @inputData
   INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' (ColumnData) VALUES (@inputData)'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@inputData VARCHAR(128)', @inputData = @inputData
```

Table name [cannot be parameterized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678725/how-to-set-table-name-in-dynamic-sql-query), so it must be appended. However, [QUOTENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) is strongly recommended to avoid SQL injection.

On the other hand, @inputData can be sent as a parameter, that's why `sp_executesql` can be used.

Generally speaking, unless you are not dealing with parameters, try to always use `sp_executesql` instead of simple `EXEC ()`, as `EXEC` forces into ugly string concatenation and possible injectable SQL statements.