# Parameterize a simple SQL update query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code as a stored procedure in SQL but it's not accepting the @DBNAME stating it needs to be declared but I already declared it.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateSQL
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@UpdateField varchar(25),
@UpdateValue varchar(25),
@FilterField varchar(25),
@FilterValue varchar(25),
@DBNAME sysname

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
UPDATE @DBNAME SET @UpdateField = @UpdateValue WHERE @FilterField = @FilterValue
END
GO
```

Here is the c# function that calls the SQL procedure:

```
internal static bool UpdateSql(SqlArgs pSqlArgs)
{
    var pwd = GetPwd();
    var sqlCred = new SqlCredential(Sqluser, pwd);

    var tCatalog = GetDbo(pSqlArgs.PCatalog);

    var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection
    {
        ConnectionString = $"Data Source={SqlServer};Initial Catalog={tCatalog};",
        Credential = sqlCred
    };

    var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand
    {
        Connection = sqlConnection,
        CommandText = "UpdateSQL",
        Parameters = { new SqlParameter("@DB", pSqlArgs.PDbo), new SqlParameter("@UpdateField", pSqlArgs.PUpdateField),
            new SqlParameter("@UpdateValue", pSqlArgs.PUpdateValue), new SqlParameter("@FilterField", pSqlArgs.PFilterField),
            new SqlParameter("@FilterValue", pSqlArgs.PFilterValue) },
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
    };


    try
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();

        return sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery().Equals(1);
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($@"Error: {ex.Message}", @"Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

The ultimate function I'm trying to run is:  USE @Database UPDATE @Table SET @UpdateField = @UpdateValue WHERE @FilterField = @FilterValue

Comment: Please include your procedure run call as well.

Comment: you declared it as type sysname, but your update statement needs a table.  that is why you are getting that error.  the error actually says "must declare the table variable @dbname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use dynamic SQL, because you cannot specify table or column names as parameters in a query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateSQL
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @UpdateField varchar(25),
    @UpdateValue varchar(25),
    @FilterField varchar(25),
    @FilterValue varchar(25),
    @DBNAME sysname   
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @sql = '
UPDATE @DBNAME SET @UpdateField = @UpdateValue WHERE @FilterField = @FilterValue
';
    SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@DBNAME', @DBNAME);
    SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@UpdateField', @UpdateField);
    SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@FilterField', @FilterField);

    exec sp_executesql @sql,
                       N'@UpdateField varchar(25), @FilterField varchar(25)',
                       @UpdateField=@UpdateField, @FilterField=@FilterField;
END;
```

GO

Comment: Can I also specify a catalog with a variable or would I have to copy this procedure to each DB?

Comment: @DrewJackson . . . You can specify server, database, and schema the same way that the table and column are specified.  I'm not sure what "catalog" is in this context (normally "catalog" refers to the metadata tables about a database).

Answer (score 0):

Your code declares @DBNAME as sysname, but the update statement requires a table.

I think you might want to look at this post: [how to set table name in dynamic sql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20678725/1222227)

Also, this post talks about the same problems:  [How should I pass a table name into a stored proc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1246760/1222227)

Comment: My apologies, I'm using DBNAME as the table name, but I'm sending a table name from the calling function.