# frequently DELETE in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-delete

How I can create a stored procedure and use frequently query like this:

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @r INT;
    SET @r = 1;
    WHILE @r > 0
    BEGIN
      BEGIN TRANSACTION;
      DELETE TOP (100000)
        dbo.table1
        WHERE Create_Date < DATEADD(YEAR, -5, GETDATE());
      SET @r = @@ROWCOUNT;
      COMMIT TRANSACTION;
      CHECKPOINT;
END
```

in my new stored procedure?
Thanks for Your answers.

Comment: You want to frequently delete 100,000 records? You might want to look into maintenance plans and agent jobs.

Comment: What is the actual pattern you are looking for? What do your delete statements have in common? (e.g. different table names, different timestamp column name, but the same mechanism)

Comment: Why is transaction needed? Single `DELETE` statement does not need that.

Comment: Any triggers involved?

Comment: What is your actual question? How to create a stored procedure, or how to delete efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your `DELETE` statements dynamic using something like below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DeleteRows (
    @tableName VARCHAR(50),
    @timestampColName VARCHAR(100),
    @since DATETIME2,
    @rows INT = 100000
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @r INT;
    SET @r = 1;
    WHILE @r > 0
    BEGIN
       -- SQL injection might be a problem if table and column name are not coming from a trustworthy source (i.e. user input)
       DECLARE @SQL = N'
         DELETE TOP (' + CAST(@Count AS INT) + ')' + @tableName + '
         WHERE ' + @timestampColName + ' < @since;'

      EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@since DATETIME', @since = @since

      SET @r = @@ROWCOUNT;
    END
END
```

SQL injection can be tackled using one of the techniques indicated in [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678725/how-to-set-table-name-in-dynamic-sql-query).

Comment: I need create one stored procedure to frequently delete data in different tables and I can use the same mechanism.

Comment: @WiktorKowalczyk - yes, you can create a separate procedure from the proposed code. I have edit it to actually be inside a stored procedure.