# SQL apply join dynamically based on column names mentioned in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table for example temp

```
Id Col1 Col2 Col3
1  1     2    3
```

and I have another table joininfo

```
Id SourceKey Table TargetKey
1  Col1       A     ColA
2  Col2       B     ColB
3  Col3       C     ColC
```

I want to generate a query which will add inner join clause dynamically and will look like this

```
SELECT * FROM temp 
INNER JOIN A ON Col1=ColA 
INNER JOIN B ON Col2=ColB 
INNER JOIN C ON Col3=ColC
```

Any help?

Comment: I believe it will be generated by dynamic query and with the help of CTE

Comment: You will need to build the query dynamically and execute it with `sp_executesql`

Comment: It is usually a bad idea to store column and table names in tables - unless you are building a DBMS yourself ;-) So, the *real* solution to the problem may be another data model.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**You can build a dynamic SQL query quite neatly by using string aggregation:**

Try to keep clear about which bits are static and which dynamic. And test the generated code by using `PRINT @sql`

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'

SELECT *
FROM temp s
' +
(
    SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST(
N'JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + N' AS T' + CAST(t.object_id AS nvarchar(10)) + N' 
  ON s.' + QUOTENAME(j.SourceKey) + N' = T' + CAST(t.object_id AS nvarchar(10)) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(c.name)
    AS nvarchar(max)), N' 
') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY j.Id)
    FROM sys.tables t
    JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    JOIN joininfo j ON OBJECT_ID(j.[Table]) = t.object_id
        AND j.TargetKey = c.name
);

PRINT @sql;   -- for testing

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

If your version of SQL Server does not support `STRING_AGG` you can use `FOR XML PATH('')` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Can't do it.

SQL **needs** to know this stuff at query compile time, *before looking at any data*, so it can validate security and check for possible indexes. The only query element comes close to looking at data as if it were a column after query compile time is the `PIVOT` keyword.

Otherwise, you're down to a `CASE` expression listing every possible set of column compares, or writing dynamic SQL *over multiple steps* where you first execute a query to find what columns/joins you need, use those results to build a new query string, and then execute the string you just made.

Comment: I believe it will be generated by dynamic query and with the help of CTE

Comment: If you want to try a dynamic query, you can do that... but **try the dynamic query** first. Get as far as you can down that road and then post a new question when you get stuck. CTE has nothing to do with it and won't help you here.

Comment: For dynamic query, I am confused in looping all the rows

Comment: Okay... so post that into the question, including the code you used to make the attempt.

Comment: *"I am confused in looping all the rows"* ideally, you shouldn't be looping in your SQL anyway, @Billz . SQL is a set based language, so performs best at set based operations and poorly at iterative ones. Not sure, as well, why this has been downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment from Charlieface updating the answer using string_agg

```
    declare 
    @dsql nvarchar(max)
   
select @dsql = 'select * from temp ' + string_agg(' join '+ Table + ' on ' + c ,' ') 
from (
select Table , string_agg ( SourceKey + ' = ' + TargetKey,' and ') c
from table1
group by Table ) t
     
        select @dsql
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @dsql
```

Comment: 1 issue is here column name and join table rows are dynamic, it can be more than 3 as well

Comment: This is also **dangerously** open to injection.

Comment: @Larnu Yes I agree. Since the table name itself is dynamic, I haven't been successful on finding an alternative solution. The application need to be careful on how/who can update joininfo table. This answer is also helpful :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678725/how-to-set-table-name-in-dynamic-sql-query/29082755#29082755

Comment: @Charlieface It didn't occur to me. I updated the answer. Thank you.