# Is it possible to write a query where table name is retrieved from cell in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `dbo.TableNames` with a `varchar` column `TableName` containing table names:

```
    |    Id     | TableName             |
    +-----------+-----------------------+
    |    1      | dbo.BookDictionary    |     
    |    2      | dbo.AnotherDictionary |
```

What I am curious about, is there a way to instead of writing:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.BookDictionary
```

write something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT TableName FROM dbo.TableNames WHERE Id = 1)
```

Comment: Yes, but you have to use Dynamic SQL for this.  Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678725/how-to-set-table-name-in-dynamic-sql-query

Comment: If you *are* storing table names like this I suggest storing the schema and table name separately. Your table isn't called `dbo.BookDictionary` it's called `BookDictionary` and it's on a schema called `dbo`. Though this has the strong smell of an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is *any* chance that your `TableNames` values could be controlled by the end-user, you'll want to carefully verify the value retrieved to avoid a potential [SQL Injection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25684/how-can-i-explain-sql-injection-without-technical-jargon) attack.

```
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(max);
SELECT @TableName = TableName FROM dbo.TableNames WHERE ID = @ID;
If @TableName Is Null RAISERROR('Table %d does not exist.', 16, 1, @ID);

DECLARE @VerifiedSchemaName sysname, @VerifiedTableName sysname;

SELECT
    @VerifiedSchemaName = S.name,
    @VerifiedTableName = T.name
FROM
    sys.tables As T
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas As S
    ON S.schema_id = T.schema_id
WHERE
    @TableName = S.name + N'.' + T.name
;

If @@ROWCOUNT = 0 RAISERROR('Table "%s" does not exist.', 16, 1, @TableName);

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', 
    QUOTENAME(@VerifiedSchemaName), 
    N'.', 
    QUOTENAME(@VerifiedTableName), 
    N';');

EXEC(@sql);
```

Answer (score -1):

It is possible but i wouldnt recommend it, because it will result in performance drops quit fast

```
declare @sql varchar(max)

SELECT @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', [TableName], ';') 
FROM [dbo].[TableNames] 
WHERE Id = 1

sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Careful, this is open to injection attacks if the values in the column `TableName` are not *very* tightly controlled. Also your call to `sp_executesql` won't work as it's not the first statement in the batch and the parameter data type being wrong also generate an error.